# JQuery - Add object without interaction

Tags: jquery

We have a fixed size `<fieldset>` (1000px high) on the page we are developing. In that `<fieldset>` we dynamically create "visually graphical" objects that are drag-able so the user can position them as needed.
The objects are all created with JQuery & JS. Other objects are linked images, PNG etc... They can be placed on the same area of the page as the JS objects.
Here is the "holder for an object, each must be in a separate `<div>` to make them individually drag-able.

```
<fieldset id="OG_9" class="nm_OptionGroup" style="width:inherit;">
  <div id="OG_T_0" class="draggableObject" style="width:auto; display: inline-block;"></div>
  <div id="OG_T_1" class="draggableObject" style="width:auto; display: inline-block;"></div>
  <div id="OG_T_2" class="draggableObject" style="width:auto; display: inline-block;"></div>
</fieldset>
```

The objects are appended to the `<div>` as needed by the user, the "work area".

So, all of this works fine, but as the objects are placed/removed, from the `<fieldset>`, they interact with other objects location, corrupting their position on the screen. This destroys the users efforts.

We would like to know if it is possible that, as objects are added/deleted from the "work area", they can be prevented from interacting with each other's positioning.

Answer (score 0):

The solution...

```
<div id="draggable_1" class="dragMeToFreedom" style="width: 0; height: 0">
... the object you want to drag goes here with its own dimensions...
</div>
```

We tested it with dynamically created objects as well as .GIF etc...